# Access 2007 Exports to Excel open in old version of Excel but I want them to open in 365

Tags: microsoft-excel-365, microsoft-access-2007

My company has a database built in Access 2007. We use Office 365, but still have the old version of Access for this database. When we export from the Access database to an Excel spreadsheet, it creates a .xlsx file, but it opens in an old version of Excel instead of 365. If I close the Excel file and reopen, it opens in 365 then, and not the old version. So it's not like it's not compatible or anything. It just appears that Access 2007 just triggers it to open in an old version of Excel. Is there a way to prevent this happening, and get all excel files to be opened in 365, even if it's triggered by the Access 2007 database?

Answer (score 0):

That is a function of Access 2007 which is out of support and not being updated. So you will have to use the workaround of saving the Excel file and then re-opening in Office 365.

At some point you need to update the database to the current version and then this problem will go away.